# Pass Multiple Parameters to jQuery ajax call

Tags: asp.net, jquery, ajax

I have the following jquery code to call a webmethod in an aspx page

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "popup.aspx/GetJewellerAssets",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: '{"jewellerId":' + filter + '}',
    dataType: "json",
    success: AjaxSucceeded,
    error: AjaxFailed
});
```

and here is the web method signature

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetJewellerAssets(int jewellerId)
{
```

This works fine.

But now I need to get two parameters passed to the web method

the new web method looks like this

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetJewellerAssets(int jewellerId, string locale)
{
}
```

How do I change the client code to successfully call this new method signature ?

EDIT:

The following 2 syntaxes worked

```
data: '{ "jewellerId":' + filter + ', "locale":"en" }',
```

and

```
data: JSON.stringify({ jewellerId: filter, locale: locale }),
```

where filter and locale are local variables

Comment: `data: JSON.stringify({ jewellerId: filter, locale: locale })` is the best way which I every found, Thank @ChrisCa

Comment: If you're a sad soul like me, you might have gotten stuck on this for hours. When using `JSON.stringify` with an object literal, you MUST include the parameter name with a colon, all wrapped inside `{}` braces. Using `JSON.stringify(objectLiteral)` doesn't work.

Comment: Method signature like    `[WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)] 
        public static string TestIBAN(string ccc)` ?

Answer (score 159, accepted):

Don't use string concatenation to pass parameters, just use a data hash:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'popup.aspx/GetJewellerAssets',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: { jewellerId: filter, locale: 'en-US' },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: AjaxSucceeded,
    error: AjaxFailed
});
```

---

UPDATE:

As suggested by @Alex in the comments section, an ASP.NET PageMethod expects parameters to be JSON encoded in the request, so `JSON.stringify` should be applied on the data hash:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'popup.aspx/GetJewellerAssets',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify({ jewellerId: filter, locale: 'en-US' }),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: AjaxSucceeded,
    error: AjaxFailed
});
```

Comment: Consider also using `JSON.stringify( myObject )` to create a JSON string from a javascript object, in case you want to group your parameters to a class later on.

Comment: thanks for the replies - however, I get a http status 500 when I try it like that. Any ideas? or even how to debug it? Breakpoint in the web method never gets hit

Comment: new code as follows

$.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'popup.aspx/GetJewellerAssets',
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    data: {jewellerId:filter,locale:'en-US'},
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: AjaxSucceeded,
                    error: AjaxFailed
                });

Comment: To debug, first look at FireBug what's the exact response of the server, then put a break point in the web service method and see if it is reached.

Comment: Breakpoint in the web method never gets hit

Firebug shows: "Message":"Invalid JSON primitive: jewellerId.","StackTrace":"   at System.Web.Script.Serialization

So I guess the syntax of the json is incorrect

Comment: As @Alex suggested you need to use `JSON.stringify` like this: `data: JSON.stringify({ jewellerId: 1, locale: 'en-US' })`

Answer (score 18):

```
data: '{"jewellerId":"' + filter + '","locale":"' + locale + '"}',
```

Comment: this worked: '{ "jewellerId":' + filter + ', "locale":"en" }', (obviously I won't be hardcoding the locale to en, but this is the syntax that worked.

Comment: This worked for me with MVC 3. I couldn't get Darin's way to work - maybe its an MVC 3 thing.

Answer (score 8):

simply add as many properties as you need to the data object.

```
 $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "popup.aspx/GetJewellerAssets",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: {jewellerId: filter , foo: "bar", other: "otherValue"},
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: AjaxSucceeded,
                    error: AjaxFailed
                });
```

Comment: What would the webmethod signature look like in this case to read out the properties in `data` on the server side?

Answer (score 7):

DO not use the below method to send the data using ajax call

```
data: '{"jewellerId":"' + filter + '","locale":"' + locale + '"}'
```

If by mistake user enter special character like single quote or double quote
the ajax call fails due to wrong string.

Use below method to call the Web service without any issue

```
var parameter = {
       jewellerId: filter,
       locale : locale 
};


data: JSON.stringify(parameter)
```

In above parameter is the name of javascript object and stringify it when passing it to the data attribute of the ajax call.

Answer (score 5):

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'popup.aspx/GetJewellerAssets',      
    data: "jewellerId=" + filter+ "&locale=" +  locale,  
    success: AjaxSucceeded,
    error: AjaxFailed
});
```

Comment: Working too using ***type: GET*** ?

Comment: or you can use an array to pass data in jason.stringyfy(array).

Answer (score 3):

Has anyone else noticed that the json string/object is invalid in all answers except for David Hedlund's? :)

JSON objects must be formatted in the following manner: {"key": ("value" | 0 | false)}. Also, writing it out as a string requires much less than stringifying the object...

Answer (score 3):

```
    var valueOfTextBox=$("#result").val();
    var valueOfSelectedCheckbox=$("#radio:checked").val();

    $.ajax({
    url: 'result.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { forValue: valueOfTextBox, check : valueOfSelectedCheckbox } ,
    beforeSend: function() {

          $("#loader").show();
       },
    success: function (response) {
       $("#loader").hide();
       $("#answer").text(response);
    },
    error: function () {
        //$("#loader").show();
        alert("error occured");
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to add on [This line perfectly work in Asp.net& find web-control Fields in jason Eg:<%Fieldname%>]

```
 data: "{LocationName:'" + document.getElementById('<%=txtLocationName.ClientID%>').value + "',AreaID:'" + document.getElementById('<%=DropDownArea.ClientID%>').value + "'}",
```

Answer (score 0):

Its all about data which you pass; has to properly formatted string.
If you are passing empty data  then  data: {} will work.
However with multiple parameters it has to be properly formatted
e.g.

```
var dataParam = '{' + '"data1Variable": "' + data1Value+ '", "data2Variable": "' + data2Value+ '"' +  '}';
```

....

data : dataParam

...

Best way to understand is have error handler with proper message parameter, so as to know the detailed errors.

Answer (score 0):

I successfully passed multiple parameters using json

```
data: "{'RecomendeeName':'" + document.getElementById('txtSearch').value + "'," + "'tempdata':'" +"myvalue" + "'}",
```

Comment: never pass user data to a parameter without 'cleaning' before.

Answer (score -1):

```
            data: JSON.stringify({ "objectnameOFcontroller": data, "Sel": $(th).val() }),
```

controller object name