# How to pass Multiple Parameters from ajax call to MVC Controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I have the controller like the below:

```
public ActionResult Save(string input, string name) {
    //Some code
    return PartialView();
}
```

And I need an ajax call to this controller method and pass the two arguments input and value

And my ajax call is like the below:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Home/Save',
    type: 'POST',
    async: false,
    dataType: 'text',
    processData: false,
    data: "input=" + JSON.stringify(data) + "&name =" + $("#name").val(),
    success: function (data) {
    }
});
```

I am unable to pass the value to the name parameter. The value in the name parameter is becoming null.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery Ajax call - data parameters are not being passed to MVC Controller action](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002163/jquery-ajax-call-data-parameters-are-not-being-passed-to-mvc-controller-action)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You're making an HTTP POST, but trying to pass parameters with the GET query string syntax. In a POST, the data are passed as named parameters and do not use the `param=value&foo=bar` syntax. Using jQuery's ajax method lets you create a javascript object with the named parameters, like so:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/Home/SaveChart',
  type: 'POST',
  async: false,
  dataType: 'text',
  processData: false,    
  data: { 
      input: JSON.stringify(IVRInstant.data), 
      name: $("#wrkname").val()
  },
  success: function (data) { }
});
```

Comment: I believe that by default, forms with a POST method to submit a URI string in the body of the message.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to posts by @xdumain, I prefer creating data object before ajax call so you can debug it.

```
var dataObject = JSON.stringify({
                    'input': $('#myInput').val(),
                    'name': $('#myName').val(),
                });
```

Now use it in ajax call

```
$.ajax({
          url: "/Home/SaveChart",
          type: 'POST',
          async: false,
          dataType: 'json',
          contentType: 'application/json',
          data: dataObject,
          success: function (data) { },
          error: function (xhr) { }            )};
```

Answer (score 0):

I did that with helping from this question

[jquery get querystring from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4656873/4251431)

so let see how
we will use this function

```
// Read a page's GET URL variables and return them as an associative array.
function getUrlVars()
{
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
    {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars;
}
```

and now just use it in `Ajax call`

```
"ajax": {
    url: '/Departments/GetAllDepartments/',                     
    type: 'GET',                       
    dataType: 'json',                       
    data: getUrlVars()// here is the tricky part
},
```

thats all, but if you want know `how to use this function` or `not send all the query string parameters` back to [actual answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4656873/4251431)

Answer (score 0):

```
function final_submit1() {
    var city = $("#city").val();
    var airport = $("#airport").val();

    var vehicle = $("#vehicle").val();

    if(city && airport){
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        cache:false,
        data:{"city": city,"airport": airport},
        url:'http://airportLimo/ajax-car-list', 
        success: function (html) {
             console.log(html);
          //$('#add').val('data sent');
          //$('#msg').html(html);
           $('#pprice').html("Price: $"+html);
        }
      });

    }  
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  url: "ChnagePassword.aspx/AutocompleteSuggestions",
  data: "{'searchstring':'" + request.term + "','st':'Arb'}",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function (data) {
     response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
         return { value: item }
     }))
  },
  error: function (result) {
      alert("Error");
  }
});
```

Comment: Please add some commentary on how this answers the question and use proper formatting