# This jquery function doesn't complete but also doesn't throw any errors

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to work out why this function isn't working by placing a few alerts all the way through it.

I get the first 'hmmm' alert, but then nothing after that.

If I look at firebug, I can see that I actually get the returned json data I desire, so obviously the ajax request is a success.... but so why is nothing on the inside of the success return doing anything?

```
alert('hmm'); // <- i work

$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: '/process_registration.php',
data: {event: event_id, time: time_id, ticket: ticket_id, tix: number_tickets, sta: cc_state, type: cc_type, e: reg[0], m: reg[1], f:reg[2], l:reg[3], cc:reg[4], cvn:reg[5], mo:reg[6], yr:reg[7], st:reg[8], city:reg[9], p:reg[10], tot:total },
cache: false,
dataType: 'json',
success: function(data) {

alert('hi1'); // <- why don't I get inside here and work?

        if(data['success']=='1'){
        window.location.href = '/registration_complete';
        }

    if(data['unknown']=='1' ||  data['error']=='1') {

        alert('hi your submission failed');

    }

 }

});
```

I'm used to seeing some errors if this sort of thing happens but I'm not getting anything back from the browser to debug it. I'm sure its something simple and will reveal a new dimension to my stupidity.

Please help :)

Here is an example submission of the data which firebug says is being posted in the ajax post:

```
cc  3242324232423242
city    oasuht
cvn 122
e   tohaeus@email.com
event   22
f   soatehu
l   sntahou
m   23423424
mo  12
p   234234
st  aoesntuh asotenhu
sta State
ticket  37 
time    120
tix 4
tot 4.00
yr  12
```

So it appears all the data is going across and shouldn't be the issue to me.

Comment: Remove `data` parameter and tell us what you see. If it changes nothing, then please go to the URL it should call and then tell us what happens (eg. is there a redirection of some sort?).

Comment: It changes nothing I'm afraid - I still get a return of the json data, in this case -> "{"error":"1"}{"error_msg":" Invalid Expiry Date. Your credit card has not been billed for this transaction."}" because we didn't send any data for the expiry date of the credit card.

Comment: add `error: function(xhr,status,error) {...}` callback and see if that's being called because of an error.

Comment: A alerted those and got: xhr: [object XMLHttpRequest] status: parsererror error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

Comment: I think your script isn't returning valid json data....

Comment: Possibly - does this look invalid though? {"error":"1"}{"error_msg":" Invalid Expiry Date. Your credit card has not been billed for this transaction."}

Comment: I just ran it through a validator and you are right sally!! the json is invalid.

Comment: It was just a guess mate, that's good it worked for you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your using the `success` callback, which won't be called if the request is unsuccessful.

Take a look at the [*other* callbacks](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

- `complete`
- `error`
- `statusCode`

Comment: Thanks for that i'll check them out. But isn't it successful if I'm getting the returned json data? Doesn't 'success' simply mean it found the file and loaded? The json data I'm getting back is from this processing of the ajax loaded file...

Comment: @apaidnerd: Thanks. Not sure why I didn't include it in my exhaustive list.

Comment: I think that means that your JSON is invalid. Try running it through a validator and see where it hiccups.

Answer (score 1):

did you check it with firebug to see the exact error you are getting? You can also add an error function in your ajax call. If that is hit, there is some problem with your data :)

You can use json2.js and use JSON.stringify to post your data. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7977533/pass-multi-parameters-in-jquery-ajax-script/7977810#7977810) might work

Comment: try putting an error function too and let me know if it is hit. its always good to have one

Comment: no rocket science in that. insert a , after success and then add error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {}

Comment: Then this should solve your issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/631418/jquery-getjson-ajax-parseerror

Comment: "xhr: [object XMLHttpRequest] status: parsererror error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token {"

Comment: add a breakpoint and scrutinize your data for invalid tokens. see my edit for a possible answer to your problem

Answer (score 1):

write exit; right after you json_encode($data); in your php file and then give it a try.