# Passing multiple parameters in ajax is giving me error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, webmethod

I want to pass multiple parameters to my `ajax` code. Which is `3` parameters. So, I added like below

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        SearchText();
    });
    function SearchText() {
        $("#txt712").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "FrmAgreementMaster.aspx/GetAutoCompleteData",
                    //data: "{'username':'" + extractLast(request.term) + "'}",
                    data: JSON.stringify("{'username':'" + extractLast(request.term) + "'}", "{'taluka':'" + document.getElementById('ddlTaluka').value + "'}", "{'village':'" + document.getElementById('ddlVillage').value + "'}"),
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        response(data.d);
                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        alert("Error");
                    }
                });
            },
            focus: function () {
                return false;
            },
            select: function (event, ui) {
                var terms = split(this.value);
                terms.pop();
                terms.push(ui.item.value);
                terms.push("");
                this.value = terms.join(", ");
                return false;
            }
        });
        $("#txt712").bind("keydown", function (event) {
            if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
                $(this).data("autocomplete").menu.active) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        })
        function split(val) {
            return val.split(/,\s*/);
        }
        function extractLast(term) {
            return split(term).pop();
        }
    }
```

By taking reference from [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916309/pass-multiple-parameters-to-jquery-ajax-call) of `Darin's` code.

But it is taking me to `ERROR` part while calling the function. How do I pass multiple parameters to use it.

**update**

Also, I took the ajax reference from [here](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/07/jquery-autocomplete-textbox-with.html)

Response code:-

```
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
[WebMethod]
public static List<string> GetAutoCompleteData(string username, string taluka, string village)
{
    List<string> result = new List<string>();
    using (OracleConnection ObjPriCon = new OracleConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OracleConn"].ToString()))
    {

        using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("select distinct survey_area_7_12 FROM xxcus.xxacl_pn_farming_mst WHERE survey_area_7_12  " +
                                                     "LIKE '%' || :searchtext || '%' and taluka = '" + taluka + "' and village = '" + village + "'", ObjPriCon))
        {
            ObjPriCon.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(":searchtext", username.ToLower());
            OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    result.Add(dr["survey_area_7_12"].ToString());
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: add data:     JSON.stringify("{'username':'" + extractLast(request.term) + "','taluka':'" + document.getElementById('ddlTaluka').value + "','village':'" + document.getElementById('ddlVillage').value + "'}"),      single json string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need multiple object, you need multiple properties in a object

```
 data: JSON.stringify({username: extractLast(request.term) , taluka: $('#ddlTaluka').val(), village:$('#ddlVillage').val()}),
```

Ps: Don't forget that you trigger the autocomplete at page ready, make sure you have values in those inputs

Comment: tried this too, not woking.. Getting same `error` alert

Comment: @madalinivascu, it's funny that we suggested the solution specific to the problem and have no upvotes, while the other answer suggesting generic approach gets upvotes. go figure

Comment: i am not familiar with .net but you are returning text instead of json, and you are sending json , does your .net function accept json as input?

Comment: what response code does your xhr request have? 404 500 ?

Comment: @madalinivascu: how do I check that? as of now it gives me alert as `Error`.

Comment: go to the developer tools on the tab network do a page refresh with the tab open ,after the page is fully loaded look for a request type xhr with your ajax request url you will see there the response code and the page preview as well

Comment: Getting preview something like this `{Message: "Invalid JSON primitive: username.",…}
ExceptionType
:
"System.ArgumentException"
Message
:
"Invalid JSON primitive: username."
StackTrace
:
"   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializePrimitiveObject()
↵`

Comment: anything which  I missed ?

Comment: the json seems to be invalid , try the updated answer or set processData to false

Comment: are you their ?

Comment: Upvoting ur answer though. THANKS :)

Answer (score 5):

You can pass multiple params like:

```
$.ajax({
...
data: {
    var1: val1,
    var2: val2,
    var3: val3,
    var4: val4,
    // and many more
}
...
});
```

In case you want to pass an array, than you can use 'JSON.stringify'.

Answer (score 1):

Try to pass data like this:

```
data: JSON.stringify([
    {username: extractLast(request.term)},
    {taluka: document.getElementById('ddlTaluka').value},
    {village: document.getElementById('ddlVillage').value}
]),
```

Or like this:

```
data: {
    username: extractLast(request.term),
    taluka: document.getElementById('ddlTaluka').value,
    village: document.getElementById('ddlVillage').value
},
```

Comment: tried both ur code, but getting into error part `error: function (result) {
                            alert("Error");
                        }`

Comment: how does a query look? check in network tab. and what's in the result?

Comment: query is smoething like this `SELECT DISTINCT survey_area_7_12 FROM xxcus.xxacl_pn_farming_mst WHERE survey_area_7_12 LIKE '%' || :searchtext || '%' AND taluka = '3' AND village = '1'` and the result is `32/0
 30/2`

Comment: no, I mean HTTP query, check [the network tab](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AXGB4tIRNgM)

Comment: Getting preview something like this `{Message: "Invalid JSON primitive: username.",…} ExceptionType : "System.ArgumentException" Message : "Invalid JSON primitive: username." StackTrace : " at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer‌​.DeserializePrimitiv‌​eObject() ↵`

Comment: we need to see what goes from a browser, let's discuss in chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127693/discussion-between-maximus-and-nad).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to assign an object containing the key value pair of your data to the data attribute of your ajax call.

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: url,
   data: {
      'name': $('#name').val(),
      'email': $('#email').val(),
      // so on...
   }
})
```

and then you can simply get them in your post request by the names you specify here.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to do this.

```
 $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "FrmAgreementMaster.aspx/GetAutoCompleteData",
                //data: "{'username':'" + extractLast(request.term) + "'}",

        data: JSON.stringify({
            username: extractLast(request.term),taluka:document.getElementById('ddlTaluka').value,village:document.getElementById('ddlVillage').value
        }),
                error: function (result) {
                    alert("Error");
                }
            });
```