# pass arrays and variables from jquery to php at the same time

Tags: php, jquery

I want to pass arrays and other variables from jquery code to php using post request but I don't know how to pass arrays and variables at the same time.

**I tried this code:**

```
var new_location_name = "";
var new_location_id = "";
var old_location_name = [];
var selected_name = [];
var selected_id = [];
var user = '<?php echo $current_user ;?>';

    $(document).ready(
           $("#transfer").click(function(){
                 $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "update.php",
                    data: "username="+user+"&new_location_name="+new_location_name+"&new_location_id"+new_location_id+"&"+{ old_location_name : old_location_name }+"&"+{ selected_name : selected_name }+"&"+{ selected_id : selected_id },
                });
                 return false;
            });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass multiple parameters as arrays or strings the same.  The left hand side of the data is the value that the API is expecting as the parameter name.

```
var new_location_name = "";
var new_location_id = "";
var old_location_name = [];
var selected_name = [];
var selected_id = [];
var user = '<?php echo $current_user ;?>';

    $(document).ready(
           $("#transfer").click(function(){
                 $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "update.php",
                    data: {username: user, 
                           new_location_name: new_location_name,
                          old_location_name: old_location_name
                      }
                });
                 return false;
            });
    });
```

You can read more in this question: [Pass Multiple Parameters to jQuery ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916309/pass-multiple-parameters-to-jquery-ajax-call)

Comment: thanks for the quick response, if I sent arrays and variables like this what would I need to do on the other side at the php file to get the value of each array and each variable?

Comment: They would just be parameters on the php function and then you can access them as JSON.

Answer (score 2):

Create an object, serialize it and send it:

```
var obj = {
   key1: 'value1',
   key2: ['one','two','three'],
   key3: {
      key3_0: 'value3_0'
   }
}
var jsonData = JSON.stringify(obj);

$.ajax({
     method: "POST",
     url: "update.php",
     data: jsonData
});
```

Answer (score 1):

JQuery Data:

```
data: 
    {
        username: user, 
        new_location_name: new_location_name, 
        new_location_id: new_location_id, 
        old_location_name: old_location_name, 
        selected_name : selected_name, 
        selected_id : selected_id 
    }
```

In your PHP Script

```
<? $oldLocationName = $_REQUEST['old_location_name']; ?>
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet

```
var array = [];
$.ajax({ url: 'update.php',
    data: {'array' : array},
    type: 'post',
    dataType:'json',
    success: function(output) {
        alert(output);
    },
    error: function(request, status, error) {
       alert("Error");
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

First time Check file, this script must be in .php file, not .js file;