# Pass second argument to AJAX function from Model in View

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I have the following button which imports a file. I am passing the file to a function, but I also need to pass an id from the model of the view which I am checking if it is null before showing the import button (Model.OrganizationId)

```
@if (Model.OrganizationId != null)
        {
            <input type="file" id="fileInput" value="Import" style="display: none;" onchange="uploadFile(this)" />
            <input class="buttons import" style="width: 12.5em" readonly="readonly" onclick="document.getElementById('fileInput').click();" value="Import" />
        }
```

This is the uploadFile function:

```
    function uploadFile(fileCtrl,id) {

        showLoading();
        var formData = new FormData();
        if (fileCtrl.files.length > 0) {
            formData.append('Excel', fileCtrl.files[0]);

            $.ajax({
                url: actionUrl("Action", "Controller", null, "Area"),
                type: "POST",
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data:  formData,
                success: function (data) {
---------
```

How can I pass that second parameter so my controller

```
public JsonResult Import(FormCollection form, long? organizationId)
        {
```

can take that organizationId?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916309/pass-multiple-parameters-to-jquery-ajax-call

Answer (score 0):

Easiest would be to change your data parameter to something like this:

```
data: { form: formData , organizationId: '<your id>' },
```